# How do I start a console application in one project from a web form in another project?

Tags: vb.net, webforms, console-application

I have a website created in VS 2010 with .NET 4.0.  There are multiple projects in the solution.  In one of the projects I have a form that gives a user the option to run a console application that is in another project of the solution. (called update.exe)

I have tried just using

**process.start(filepath + "update.exe")**

but it doesn't seem to run.

It finds the file but then finishes immediately.  I tried adding **Console.readKey()** to the console application so it would stay open after being called, but it was to no avail.

On top of this, I know that the console app isn't running as I have logs set up throughout the console's code and it never even seems to kick off.

Should I be calling the console app differently?  (note: I am writing in VB.net)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Purely speculative here.. but my guess is that when the page finishes processing the process is terminated.  Try having the page wait for the process to close.

Comment: No luck..  Hmm.. I altered my code to define a process ('objProgress'), start the process, and then wait using the line: 'objProcess.WaitForExit()'  However, it just sat there for about 15 minutes before I stopped it.  This is a process that normally takes 3 minutes max.  Still no logs being entered either.

Answer (score 0):

My 'work-around' for a similar requirement is this:

Use the ASP page to create a CMD or BAT file on the server.
Create/write a service that 'watches' for the CMD/BAT file - and when it finds one, it runs it. The service can be written to start a process as a user.